# Extracting file directory from a .txt file?

Tags: python, csv, file

I have a text file known as `testConfigFile` which is as follow :

```
inputCsvFile = BIN+"/testing.csv"
description = "testing"
```

In which `BIN` is my parent directory of the folder (already declared using `os.getcwd` in my python script).

The problem I'm facing now is, how to read and extract the `BIN+"testing.csv"` from the `testConfigFile.txt`.

Since the name `testing.csv` might be changed to other names, so it will be a variable. I'm planning to do something like, first the script reads the keyword `"inputCsvFile = "` then it will automatically extract the words behind it, which is `"BIN+"testing.csv"`.

```
f = open("testConfigFile","r")
line = f.readlines(f)
if line.startswith("inputCsvFile = ")
  inputfile = ...
```

This is my failed partial code, where I've no idea on how to fix it. Is there anyone willing to help me?

Comment: `line` will be a list, you can't use `startswith` on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading a config off a unstructured txt file is not the best idea. Python actually is able to parse config files that are structured in a certain way. I have restructured your txt file so that it is easier to work with. The config file extension does not really matter, I have changed it to .ini in this case.

app.ini:

```
[csvfilepath]
inputCsvFile = BIN+"/testing.csv"
description = "testing"
```

Code:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser  # Available by default, no install needed.

config = ConfigParser()  # Create a ConfigParser instance.
config.read('app.ini')  # You can input the full path to the config file.

file_path = config.get('csvfilepath', 'inputCsvFile')
file_description = config.get('csvfilepath', 'description')

print(f"CSV File Path: {file_path}\nCSV File Description: {file_description}")
```

Output:

```
CSV File Path: BIN+"/testing.csv"
CSV File Description: "testing"
```

To read more about configparser, you may refer [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html).

For a simple tutorial on configparser, you may refer [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBwfq6UMxkY).